# creating a struct in Julia based on variable input

Tags: struct, julia

I am new to Julia and trying to learn something with a neural network project. 
I would like to create a structure for a network based on how many layers I give as input. This is based on an example from over here: (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#implementing_our_network_to_classify_digits). (which is excellent)

I am copying code from that text:

```py
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) 
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

In this code, the list sizes contains the number of neurons in the respective layers. So, for example, if we want to create a Network object with 2 neurons in the first layer, 3 neurons in the second layer, and 1 neuron in the final layer, we'd do this with the code:

```
net = Network([2, 3, 1])"
```

I've tried something similar in Julia:

```
struct NTWRK(nt)
    numlayers=length(nt)
    Nsizes=nt
    biases= [rand(Float32,nt[i+1]) for i=1:length(nt)-1]
    weights=[rand(Float32,(nt[i+1],nt[i])) for i=1:length(nt)-1]
end

network=NTWRK([784, 16, 16, 10])
```

and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax: "numlayers = length(nt)" inside type definition is reserved
Stacktrace:
   [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I tried various things and I just can't get some object with all the intended fields based on the input I give at the start. Any advice?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `struct NTWRK` is a type definition, but you are treating it as if it were a function. `struct NTWRK(nt)` is not valid syntax.

Comparing it to your Python code, you should realize that `__init__()` is a constructor function, so to do the same thing in Julia you also need a constructor.

So first you need to declare the type, and then, you can define the constructor(s).

```
# First, the declaration of the struct
struct NTWRK
    Nsizes::Vector{Int}
    biases::Vector{Vector{Float32}} 
    weights::Vector{Matrix{Float32}}
end

# There has already been automatically created a constructor, but we want
# to create one that accepts just a single input argument:
function NTWRK(nt::Vector)
    biases = [rand(Float32,nt[i+1]) for i in 1:length(nt)-1]
    weights = [rand(Float32,(nt[i+1],nt[i])) for i in 1:length(nt)-1]
    return NTWRK(nt, biases, weights) # here we call the pre-existing constructor
end
numlayers(nw::NTWRK) = length(nw.Nsizes)
```

I moved `numlayers` outside the struct itself, because it seemed pointless to store it as a separate field when it is trivially read from the `Nsizes` field.

Comment: Hi, this seems to work! Thank you, I appreciate it. I am not sure I fully understand what is happening yet, but I will study it a bit more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer constructor like so:

```
julia> struct NTWRK
           numlayers
           NSizes
       end

# This is the outer constructor that accepts the nt input
julia> NTWRK(nt) = NTWRK(length(nt), nt)
NTWRK

julia> NTWRK([1,2,3])
NTWRK(3, [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Never ever use untyped `struct` fields.